# Doubt about the constant 1/3 of the equation $ PV = \cfrac{1}{3} Mv_{rms}^2 $

Tags: ideal-gas

From the equation $ PV = \cfrac{1}{3} Mv_{rms}^2 $, Could someone explain to me where the 1/3 comes from?

Comment: *Unrelated*: I don't why this bothers me but try `\tfrac{1}{3}` instead of `\frac{1}{3}` for fractional coefficients. It looks a bit more streamlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a monatomic ideal gas, the average kinetic energy per particle is given by $\frac{1}{2}mv_{rms}^2= \frac{3}{2} k_BT$ via the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem).  The number 3 in the numerator of the right-hand side is due to the fact that there are three quadratic degrees of freedom in the Hamiltonian - namely, $p_x,p_y,$ and $p_z$.

Comparing this with the ideal gas law $PV=Nk_BT$, we see that $PV=N\left(\frac{1}{3}mv_{rms}^2\right)= \frac{1}{3}Mv_{rms}^2$, where $M=Nm$ is the total mass of the system (the number of particles times the mass of each particle).